# how to use beforeInsert and afterInsert in grails3 domain

Tags: grails3, grails3.2.0

Iam upgrading grails2 project to grails3. i've some logic in  `beforeUpdate` and `afterInsert` but as grails3 removed `before and after interceptors`
How can i use that logic in grails3?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define a method within domain class like:

```
def beforeInsert(){
//do some stuff
}
```

Method name is important here, here is complete list of supported events/methods:

beforeInsert
beforeUpdate 
beforeDelete 
beforeValidate
afterInsert
afterUpdate
afterDelete
onLoad

source: http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/#eventsAutoTimestamping

Answer (score 0):

Think of the 'beforeInsert' and 'afterInsert' like an interceptor/filter; they are merely functions that will be triggered prior/after a insert of the data for the domain object.

It works very similar to 'before/after' for Interceptor for controllers. :)